# Scroll fixed number of items on fling/scroll to recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, smooth-scrolling, gesturedetector, fling

I have a simple activity which has a root layout.The root layout contains a recyclerview. Recyclerview will contain 20 items created from items.xml , 
which consists of 3 text views.Here items.xml represent single item in the recyclerview.

The recycler view can be scrolled both the ways , it is kind a loop of the items between 1 to 20.

I have a requirement to smoothscroll only 4 items , irrespective of the velocity of the swipe/fling.

Approaches which i have tried many approaches but coudn't succeed till now. If anyone can give any suggestions , that would be very helpful.

1. SnapHelper - this seems to snap only the item which is in the center.
2. Using gesture detector - the gestures are getting detected for all the actions , but i am unable to prevent the recyclerview's default scrolling behaviour.

The main issue is the over-scrolling of recycler view due to varing velocities of user scrolls and flings.

Here is my set up for the gesture detector.

```
public myRecyclerTouchListner(final Context context, final RecyclerView recycleView,
                                                     final LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager,
                                                     final ClickListener clicklistener){


            final ViewConfiguration vc = ViewConfiguration.get(context);
            final int swipeMinDistance = vc.getScaledPagingTouchSlop();
            final int swipeThresholdVelocity = vc.getScaledMinimumFlingVelocity();
            final int swipeMaxOffPath = vc.getScaledTouchSlop();

            this.clicklistener=clicklistener;
            simpleGestureDetector =new GestureDetector(context,new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener( ){
                @Override
                public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
                    Log.d("try", "on Fling called");
                    if(e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE &&
                            Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                        //From Right to Left
                        recycleView.smoothScrollToPosition(linearLayoutManager.
                                findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() + Constants.spanLength);
                        return true;
                    }  else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE &&
                            Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                        //From Left to Right
                        recycleView.smoothScrollToPosition(linearLayoutManager.
                                findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() - Constants.spanLength);
                        return true;
                    }

                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {


                    return true;
                }
                @Override
                public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
                    return true;
                }
                @Override
                public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
                    Log.d("Try", "Long press gesture");

                    View child=recycleView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(),e.getY());
                    if(child!=null && clicklistener!=null){
                        clicklistener.onLongClick(child,recycleView.getChildAdapterPosition(child));
                    }
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I had to use Snaphelper for custom scroll behavior in case wherein I need control over programmatic scroll and user-scroll(fling).

This was exactly what I was looking for:
[How to snap RecyclerView items so that every X items would be considered like a single unit to snap to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47514072/how-to-snap-recyclerview-items-so-that-every-x-items-would-be-considered-like-a)

I hope it will be helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that scrolling is starting from last visible position where Fling is detected and that mess up the things.

Try with global variable for example `int lastScrolledPosition = 0`;.

And `OnFling`   `recycleView.smoothScrollToPosition(lastScrolledPosition + Constants.spanLength);`

I thing this should do the trick. You should change if lastScrolledPosition < Recycleritems count.

Comment: Hi MeLine , thanks for ur answer , actually I have already implemented the same logic as u suggested , but the issue is recycle view gets over scrolled due to the varing velocity of the swipe , I want to change that behaviour.