# Pagination with multiple pages

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-paging, android-viewpager2, pagersnaphelper

I’m trying to get pagination with a fixed number of views per swipe (1 row with a fixed number of columns). For example: 0 1 2 3, next horizontal swipe items: 4 5 6 7 , next horizontal swipe 8 9 10 11 etc.

Already tried:

1. PagerSnapHelper - gives me only 1 item per view
2. ViewPager2 - only 1 page per view
3. RecyclerView with gridLayoutManager + PagerSnapHelper - When using GridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, second parameter will be considered as number of rows, and I want 1 row, and a fixed number of columns.
4. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47514072/how-to-snap-recyclerview-items-so-that-every-x-items-would-be-considered-like-a)  - I prefer Android built-in solution, if exist.

Please I don’t want to use 3rd-party library / code. Any suggestions? Thanks.